# I have a path of file in txt file which contains filename at last. how to distinguish between path and file through bash script

Tags: bash, unix

Suppose, i having a path and file name in a single line of txt file. below is the example

folder/folder1/folder2/folder3/filename.txt

Now i want to get this whole path so that i can reach to the file. I can get the filename by using awk separated by first '/' reading in reverse order(using NF). But not sure how to get full path.

My output should contain
folder/folder1/folder2/folder3

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a lot of ways, actually...

Let's pretend that you have your line of text in a var named `line`.

As suggested by @Cyrus, you can use:

```
dirname "${line}"
```

Please, note that this will be a relative path, just as you provide it in your txt file. ([relative vs absolute path](https://www.linuxnix.com/abslute-path-vs-relative-path-in-linuxunix/)
)

If you need a full path, you can use:

```
line="$(readlink -f "${line}")"
printf "%s" "${line##*/}"
```

Note that both `dirname` and `readlink` are binaries and not built-ins in bash, so they could not work on some system (E.G. macOS).
In this case, you can use `brew install coreutils` to install `coreutils`. (You can get brew [here](https://brew.sh/).)

They however can be considered portable, if you aim for portability.

Hope this helps.

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), note the section "Answer Well-Asked Questions", and the bullet point therein regarding questions which "have already been asked and answered many times before".

Comment: BTW, reliance on having *some* kind of `readlink` is indeed reasonably portable, but the `-f` argument is a GNUism; Apple's `readlink` only accepts one option, that being `-n`. Unless one needs to handle the case of a path that doesn't include any `/` at all, consider using [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) anyhow -- `line=${line%/*}` is not only guaranteed to be supported on any POSIX shell, but also is evaluated internally, and is thus much faster than calling out to an external utility. (See also [BashFAQ #100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100)).